# CSS - How to color special shape on hover?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I've created a "tag" shape using CSS (the rectangular base + triangle). Since I have more than one tag shape I wanted to add the `hover` property to the class which defines that shape and that way automatically attach `hover` to all tags. However, it appears its not working and the only way to apply `hover` is by `id`. Why is that? There surely must be an easier way to apply `hover` to several elements at once.
Second question, since tag shape is built using two shapes, how should the `hover` color transition should be made?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwwn2k2u/)

```
#q{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    displaY:inline-block;
    height:66px;
    padding: 0 35px 0 20px;


    font-size: 25px;
    line-height:65px;

    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 20px 25px;

    background:#f3f3f3;
    transition: background 0.3s;


}

#q:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    right:-19px;
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:18px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top:  33px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 33px solid transparent;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}

#q:hover{
    background: green;
    border-left:18px solid lightblue;

}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="pricetag-right" id="q">tag is here!</span>
```

Comment: You can combine rules with a comma, like `#q:hover, #q:hover:after`

Comment: You should consider using `scss` or `less` instead of manually write CSS, then you have automatic snippets which does all that for you already in a much more readable manner. Look these up on codepen.io

Answer (score 4):

### [DEMO PAGE](https://jsfiddle.net/bwwn2k2u/3/)

```
#q{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    displaY:inline-block;
    height:66px;
    padding: 0 35px 0 20px;


    font-size: 25px;
    line-height:65px;

    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 20px 25px;

    background:#f3f3f3;
    transition: background 0.3s;


}

#q:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    right:-19px;
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:18px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top:  33px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 33px solid transparent;
    transition: border 0.3s;
}

#q:hover{
    background: green;
}

#q:hover:after{
    border-left-color:green;
}
```

You needed to set the `transition` of the `:after` to `border` and not `background`, since it's the border property being transitioned.

Comment: Thanks. How about the second question, add `hover` to the class and use the class selector instead of the id?

Comment: why add a `hover` class (with javascript)? i'm curious

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle based on vsync's with class selectors:

https://jsfiddle.net/ajanini/9z3Lvp90/

```
.pricetag-right{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    displaY:inline-block;
    height:66px;
    padding: 0 35px 0 20px;


    font-size: 25px;
    line-height:65px;

    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 20px 25px;

    background:#f3f3f3;
    transition: background 0.3s;


}

.pricetag-right:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    right:-19px;
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:18px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top:  33px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 33px solid transparent;
    transition: border 0.3s;
}

.pricetag-right:hover{
    background: green;
}

.pricetag-right:hover:after{
    border-left-color:green;
}
```